# Creating a function in R with an argument whose inputs begin with a number

Tags: r, function, parsing, arguments

I do apologize if this has been answered somewhere but I can't find a question similar to it anywhere.

I am trying to create a function where one of the input arguments could be (but isn't necessarily) a string which begins with a number. When I try to run this function, R get confused.

For example:

```
foo(df, 10, 5fum)
```

gives me the error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "do_cv_class(data,10,5fum"

In the function I plan on taking `"5fum"` and parsing it into 2 arguments `"5"` and `"fum"`. I don't want to create a 4th argument to separate 5 and fum.

Any ideas? Any help on this would great.

Comment: When you pass a string argument to a function, enclose it in quotes. e.g.: `fun(df, 10, "5fum")`

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around it? Otherwise it will be considered a variable.

Comment: also, you can not create variable, which starts with number

Comment: @Zbynek, you can (`"5fum" <- "hello"`), but it is not good practice.  Poster, you should read some intro R texts (e.g. section 2.6 of [Intro to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)).  Your question betrays ignorance of some very fundamental R principles.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments above suggest, you need to pass `"5fum"` as a string. Without rewriting R's parser, it's almost impossible to think of a way that `foo(df, 10, 5fum)` could be legal input. Presumably you're thinking about something like this:

```
foo <- function(df, num1, str1) {
   str1_num <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)","\\1",str1))
   str1_alpha <- gsub("([0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+)","\\2",str1)
   print(str1_num)
   print(str1_alpha)
}

foo(df, 10, "5fum")
## [1] 5
## [1] "fum"
```

(I thought passing the argument as something like `~5fum` might work, as the `~` prevents subsequent symbols from being evaluated immediately, but it doesn't: the symbol `5fum` still needs to be parsed.)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, that would be a simple fix. I should've mentioned earlier that I'm wondering if there a way to do so without the forcing the user to enter the argument as quotes.

Comment: I would say that is impossible.  The requirement that symbols start with non-numeric values is very deeply ingrained into R's parser.

Comment: Thanks! I will go the other route then. I really appreciate the help!